# Problems using gradient boosting classifier in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use the gradient boosting classifier `ensemble.gradientBoostingClassifier` in Scikit-learn for python, but I keep getting these error messages:

```
Floating point exception: 8
```

and

```
Python quit unexpectedly while using the _tree.so plug-in.
```

Reading [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1406), I get the impression that it is due to a change in NumPy, but I can't see if anyone have solved it yet?

I am running the following versions:

- Scikit-learn: `0.13-git`
- NumPy: `1.8.0.dev-20224ea`

Comment: When you say: Scikit-learn: '0.13-git' does it mean that you have `git pull`ed the master branch of the main repo and did a rebuild of scikit-learn after the fix for issue #1406? If so could you please report this as a crash on the issue tracker of the project? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues

Comment: Thanks for helping! I did run [git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git], but it didn't make things better. Should I do anything else to make sure I have the latest Scikit release?

Comment: You are on the development source code which is not released yet. So it's even more up to date than the latest release.

Are you sure that the sklearn you import is not pointing to an old version you installed in the past? Try: python -c "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__file__)"

Comment: I get: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/__init__.pyc

Comment: So if you recently installed from the latest clone (with `python setup.py install`), it means that we still have a bug in master. Please report it on the tracker.